# Combine list of objects with same superclass

Tags: polymorphism, hierarchy, superclass

Consider the following: We got a superclass Animal and two child classes Cat and Dog.
I got a method that finds all dogs and a method that finds all cats. Both return a List of dogs or cats respectively:

```
    List<Dog> dogs = getAll(Dog.class);
    List<Cat> cat = getAll(Cat.class);
```

Please have mercy with me while writing the following:

Now I want all the animals to die!

But I don't want to write something like:

```
facade.kill(dogs);
facade.kill(cats);
```

I would rather read something like:

```
facade.kill(dogsAndCats);
```

But I can't combine these two lists to one, like:

```
List<Animal> dogsAndCats = ...?
```

Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
use addAll() method in the Animal list to add Dog and Cat list.

Comment: Excuse me, forget it. Why can't you add dogs and cats in List<Animal>? If you declare the dog as an Animal like `Animal dog = new Dog()`, you should add it to the list.

Comment: Because I got a method that loads all dogs/cats from the db. Those methods return List of dogs and cats respectively.

Comment: use `addAll()` method in the `Animal` list to add `Dog` and `Cat` list.